# Can I change my Universal App to an iPad-only app without creating a new project in XCode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store, universal

I've created an iPad game using the Universal App Xcode template. Since I'm in late with the iPhone/iPod Touch branch of the app, I've decided to submit the app only for iPad and to update the app to universal in a second time.

Question: Do I have to create a new iPad project and copy there all the code and stuff, or can I simply change the deployment target to iPad only and I'm done?

I simply want to be accepted and to avoid iPhone users to be allowed to download the game erroneously.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, all you need to do is change targeted device family, check that the deployment target is iPad compatible (at least 3.2), and make sure you have all of the proper icon files and keys in `Info.plist`. Be sure to the app on an iPad, preferably 3.2 and 4.2.

In the future, another great way to tackle this is to create a new iPad Only project from the Xcode templates, and compare settings. `Info.plist` and the Target info are going to be the two main places affected.

EDIT -- As the other answer pointed out, you do indeed need to change the targeted device family to iPad. I assume this is what you meant - sorry for that.

Comment: I'll use your "cheat" of comparimg against an iPad only project too! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No, just changing the deployment target won't help!
However, you can edit the `Targeted Device Family` and set it from `iPhone/iPad` to `iPad` only. (Double click on your project -> Build Tab -> Search for the `Targeted Device Family` key -> Change the value)

Comment: Thank you, I meant target device, not deployment target, I wrote iPad only indeed ;P Thank you for your clean help!

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry for the confusion.